# oozie workflow what happened if one action fails

Tags: oozie

Recently got this question from one of my friend but i am not sure how it works in oozie.

Question:

What happens if one action fails in workflow(assume multiple actions are there) and when we restart again whether it starts from failed action or start from previously completed action.

Please clarify this doubt.

Thanks

Saravan

Answer (score 0):

This property comes into the consideration, `oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes` if `true`: It will start from the failed node, `false`: it will start from the start.